# How to fix issue: no rule to process file /FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap' of type 'sourcecode.module-map' for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, fbsdk

I'm creating an app and I'm on the first step of setting up Firebase social login and I got this error suddenly,

Showing Recent Issues

> :-1: no rule to process file
>   '/Users/Al/Desktop/CB.FireBaseSocialLogin/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Basics/FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap'
>   of type 'sourcecode.module-map' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target
>   'FBSDKCoreKit')

no other errors are showing and the app runs with a blank white screen. the header files in my compiler sources are AppDelegate.swift and ViewController.swift.

I'm using Xcode 10.2.1

///this is the output i'm seeing:

> 2019-05-28 12:43:56.393901+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343]
>   : Please set a value for FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set
>   the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and
>   in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before
>   collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once
>   user consent is received. Learn more:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
>   2019-05-28 12:43:56.394525+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343]
>   : You haven't set a value for
>   FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you
>   want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics
>   results. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag
>   value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received.
>   Learn more:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
>   2019-05-28 12:43:56.437230+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343]
>   libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not
>   supported on this platform. 2019-05-28 12:43:56.440128+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612520]  - [I-ACS036002]
>   Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics
>   setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the
>   default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag
>   FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
>   2019-05-28 12:43:56.497990+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343]
>   Unknown class _TtC22CB_FireBaseSocialLogin14ViewController in
>   Interface Builder file. 2019-05-28 12:43:56.535539+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343] Falling back to loading access
>   token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug 2019-05-28
>   12:43:56.535719+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343] Falling back
>   to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
>   2019-05-28 12:43:56.566347+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343]
>   FBSDKLog: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection cannot be started before
>   Facebook SDK initialized. 2019-05-28 12:43:56.582737+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343] FBSDKLog:
>   FBSDKGraphRequestConnection cannot be started before Facebook SDK
>   initialized. 2019-05-28 12:43:56.583098+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343] FBSDKLog:
>   FBSDKGraphRequestConnection cannot be started before Facebook SDK
>   initialized. 2019-05-28 12:43:56.588004+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612526] 6.0.0 -
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60000000 started
>   2019-05-28 12:43:56.588883+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612526]
>   6.0.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
>   http:1234567890) 2019-05-28 12:43:56.621611+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343] [MC] System group container for
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/Al/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A4CCED21-B5C8-4C67-81A5-2BC39E842757/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2019-05-28 12:43:56.621979+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612343]
>   [MC] Reading from private effective user settings. 2019-05-28
>   12:43:57.138534+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612526] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7f9759a04710]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-05-28 12:43:57.138675+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612526] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7f9759a04710]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-05-28 12:43:57.139153+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612526] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-05-28 12:43:57.139250+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612526]
>   TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57 2019-05-28 12:43:57.215138+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7f9759b01f60]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-05-28 12:43:57.215290+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7f9759b01f60]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-05-28 12:43:57.215539+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-05-28 12:43:57.215624+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528]
>   TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57 2019-05-28 12:43:57.366695+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7f97574138a0]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-05-28 12:43:57.366837+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x7f97574138a0]
>   get output frames failed, state 8196 2019-05-28 12:43:57.367263+0300
>   CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
>   2019-05-28 12:43:57.367555+0300 CB.FireBaseSocialLogin[7764:612528]
>   TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's a interesting error but for this site to work for you, we would need a more complete detail of what happened to cause it. The first step is to take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The second step is to add breakpoints in your code and step through it until the error occurs. We would need to see a snippet of that code and which line threw the error. My guess is how you are initializing Firebase.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for helping me edit my question better. I tried my best to be as clear as possible but I'll edit it again.

Comment: Please remove the second detailed log from the question, it is creating clutter.

Answer (score 13):

Found How to remove the warning..

1. Select Your Pods Project
2. In Targets list select FBSDKCoreKit
3. Select "Build Phases" Tab from Top.
4. Expand the Compile Sources Tab
5. Search for "FBSDKCoreKit.modulemap" in the list.. (Uggghhhhh)
6. Select it.. Scroll down.. and click "-" (MINUS).
7. Have a happy warning free life!

[image]

Comment: Although it is a possible duplicate of a question but this should be the accepted answer.